# Invalid UTF-8 sequence with postgresql driver 9.4 and Postgres installation 9.6

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, osgi

I have installed newest PostgreSQL version: 9.6

I'm using postgresql driver version 9.4-1206-jdbc42 - I can't find newer in maven repository.

When I try to connect, I get an exception:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Ungültige UTF-8-Sequenz: das erste Byte ist 10xxxxxx: 179
    at org.postgresql.core.UTF8Encoding.decode(UTF8Encoding.java:98)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.ReceiveString(PGStream.java:327)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:424)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:203)
    ... 49 more
```

The application is deployed in OSGi container, the datasource is configured using PAX config file:

```
osgi.jdbc.driver.class=org.postgresql.Driver
url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test
dataSourceName=test
user=test
password=test
protocolVersion=3
```

What is wrong here? Is this an incompatibility between driver version and database installation? Should I downgrade?

The database uses encoding UTF-8.

In standalone java application, the following code is successful:

```
    ConnectionPool pool = new ConnectionPool();
    pool.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test");
    pool.setUser("test");
    pool.setPassword("test");
    pool.setProtocolVersion(3);
    Connection conn = pool.getConnection();
```

so it looks more like PAX issue...

Comment: `9.4-1206-jdbc42` is not that old, but the most recent is [`42.0.0`](https://jdbc.postgresql.org) is [on maven central](https://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.postgresql%7Cpostgresql%7C42.0.0.jre7%7Cbundle) (the postgresql jdbc driver jumped a lot on version numbering to avoid such misunderstandings: 9.4 should support a 9.6 server) -- also, it's 2 days old now :)

Answer (score 1):

The actual problem was somewhere else. After changing authorization method from 'md5' to 'trust' in pg_hba.conf I've got the real error message: that the role "test " could not be found.

PAX has appended trailing space to user name, which is easy to oversee, and PostgreSQL driver was unable to decode the error message from server.